# CodeLite displays non-existent errors (wxWidgets)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, wxwidgets, codelite

I created template wxwidgets application in CodeLite and it builds fine, but CodeLite shows errors like this in text editor:

[image: definition of builtin function '__rdtsc']

This error is not one, also exists error in `#include <wx/settings.h>`:
`unknown type name 'class'`.

The second error lets me understand that CodeLite is looking for `C` errors, but code on `C++`.

Is there a solution or should I ignore this errors?

Comment: Tools like IntelliSense are not perfect. There are two main reasons for their mistakes: 1. Parsing C++ is complex and means high effort. 2. Specifically in headers: Meaning of code may vary depending on where it is included. -- Due to 1., it may take time for syntax highlighting to close up or may wait for certain events to trigger it. Due to 2., there might occur ambiguities which are hard to visualize. Though, I noticed that these tools get better and better over years. At least, concerning 1., there seems to be hope...

Comment: Not a CodeLite user but in VS there is an option "Rescan Project" which helps when such errors are shown, say due to adding new file etc... Maybe there is such an option in CodeLite too.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn that off in `Plugins -> Language Server -> Settings`, but it really seems to work better and better every time, but still, the red arrows gouge out the eyes.

Here is the official link: https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Main/LanguageServer